# How to have equation number at top with intertext in split environment

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, amsmath

I have some split equations with intertext, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    y_j &= \frac{1}{35}\left(-3y_{j-2}+12y_{j-1}+17y_j+12y_{j+1}-3y_{j+2}\right),\\
    \intertext{where}
    C_{-2}&=-\frac{3}{35},C_1=\frac{12}{35},\text{etc.}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And I need the equation number to display vertically aligned with the top line, however my in the current output the equation number is at the bottom:
[image: equation]

How would I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Any reason why you do not use align here?

Comment: I can't see a reason for aligning two completely unrelated equals signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the equation number is *centered* with respect to a `split`; if the `tbtags` option is passed to `amsmath`, the number will be aligned with the top line (if on the left) or with the bottom line (if on the right).

Therefore `split` is the wrong tool, not to mention that `\intertext` makes a line as wide as `\columnwidth`, so the whole split appears to be too wide for the equation number to fit, which is the reason it is lowered below the second line.

You *could* use `align`, with `\notag` in the second line, but I see no reason for aligning unrelated `=` symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 y_j = \frac{1}{35}(-3y_{j-2}+12y_{j-1}+17y_j+12y_{j+1}-3y_{j+2}),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
C_{-2}=-\frac{3}{35},\quad C_1=\frac{12}{35},\quad\text{etc.}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to do the alignment, use `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 y_j &= \frac{1}{35}(-3y_{j-2}+12y_{j-1}+17y_j+12y_{j+1}-3y_{j+2}), \\
\shortintertext{where}
C_{-2}&=-\frac{3}{35},\quad C_1=\frac{12}{35},\quad\text{etc.} \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right, I don't need to align unrelated equations.  I forgot about starred equation environments.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'd propose to use align here.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    y_j &= \frac{1}{35}\left(-3y_{j-2}+12y_{j-1}+17y_j+12y_{j+1}-3y_{j+2}\right),\\
    \intertext{where}
    C_{-2}&=-\frac{3}{35},\quad C_1=\frac{12}{35}, \quad\text{etc.}\notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]